# Laravel Eloquent forcing my var to be a primary key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to run a migration to create a database but all changes I made end up with an error at mysql level. The Models are User, Classedeusu (class of an user) and classxusu (relation n x m, class x user).

Definition of Classedeusu (class of an user)

```
    Schema::create('classedeusus', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('classe'); //just the class name
        $table->primary('classe');
    });
```

Definition of User

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Definition of classxusu (n x m)

```
    Schema::create('classexusus', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('classe');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->primary(['classe', 'user_id']);
        $table->foreign('classe')->references('classe')->on('classedeusus');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

On classxusu, if I define the column `user_id` as `$table->integer`, I got ending up with a MySql Integer(11) signed column in `classxusus` (but on `users` table, the `$table->id` generated a Integer(10) unsigned column). If I however change that to anything other than `$table->integer` (for example, `$table->integer('user_id', 10)->unsigned()`), the column is automatically being identified as a **primary key** so I got an error in the next line at $table->primary(['classe', 'user_id']);

So, how to solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078059/laravel-scheme-builder-is-adding-auto-increment-to-all-integer-fields-which-make

Comment: This doesn't solves the problem, as I already mentioned, when I change it to `$table->integer('user_id', 10)->unsigned()` it is considered a primary key resulting in the error of the next line

Comment: For everyone sake, use English language for tables (and its fields), with correct naming conventions. What Laravel version do you use?